# Compile procedural macro code or stack values into executable?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm writing procedural macros. Let's say I have a macro to replace every instance of my password in my code with its hash. I don't want it to be included in the executable or in the memory in run time.

Are the code and stack used at compile time added into the binary file? I'm pretty sure they're not but I couldn't find an explicit answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general question is "Is there a possibility that memory from the compilation environment ends up in the final executable?".

The practical answer is No, especially related to the compiler's stack frames or memory that was used in a proc-macro (which is run in a separate process).

The answer, as far as security is concerned, is definitely Yes. For one, the compiler makes no guarantees that it does not include part of its general environment in the final executable and, for example, people have been surprised that their username gets included in the executable because a dependency generates error messages that refer to the source file where the error originated (`error at /home/myusername/foo/src/...`). Second, the compiler can't control what the operating system is doing, so part of it's own behavior (again, with respect to security guarantees) is implementation-defined there.

So, if you absolutely must guarantee that your token is not included in the final executable, hash it before even calling the compiler process in the first place.